# Defining a JSON schema with a nested array

Tags: arrays, json, nested

I'm new to JSON so bear with me please (especially if I use the wrong terminology).
I'm trying to define a JSON schema with a nested array. The idea is that there could be up to 5 customers, and **each** customer could have up to 40 account types.
This is what I've defined, but I have a feeling it's incorrect. Could someone help me please ?
(I hope I've included enough of the relevant data to make sense)

```
"type":"object",
"properties":,
    {
          "customers":{
            "description": "Contains up to 5 customers",
            "type":"array",
            "maxItems":5,       /* Here are your 5 customers */
            "minItems":0,
                "items":{
                    "type":"object",
                    "properties":,
                    {
                         "customerid_cl":{
                            "description": "ID-KUNDNR",
                            "type":"integer",
                            "maximum":999999999,
                            "minimum":000000000
                        },  
                         "ssn_number":{     
                            "description": "id_persnr",
                            "type":"string",
                            "maxLength":12,
                            "minLength":12
                        },  
                         "first_name":{
                            "description": "be_fnamn",
                            "type":"string",
                            "maxLength":15,
                            "minLength":15
                        },
                         "last_name":{
                            "description": "be_enamn",
                            "type":"string",
                            "maxLength":27,
                            "minLength":27
                        },                          
                         "deceased":{
                            "description": "FL-AVLIDEN",
                            "type":"boolean",
                        },                          
                    },                      
          "Accounts":{
            "description": "Contains up to 40 account types",
            "type":"array",
            "maxItems":40,     /* and here are the 40 account types (potentially) for EACH customer */
            "minItems":0,
                "items":{
                    "type":"object",
                    "properties":,
                    {
                         "account_number":
                        {
                            "description": "id_kontonr",
                            "type":"string",
                            "maxLength":9,
                            "minLength":1
                        },
                         "currentbalance":
                        {
                            "description": "Current account balance - how do we indicate that negative values are okay ????",
                            "type": "number",
                            "format":"decimal",
                            "maximum":999999999.99,
                            "minimum":-999999999.99
                        },**strong text**
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, "Accounts" should be a property of the customer object, so you should put it in the same level as other customer properties (like first_name, last_name,etc.). You can also find JSON schema validators online

Comment: Thank you Marko. I'll try tomorrow at work and also download a validator to help. I'll get back when I'm finished.